# Zsh: How to make `${x:?}` return non-zero in case of empty `$x`?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh, variable-substitution, parameter

How to make `${x:?}` return non-zero in case of empty `$x`? By default, it exits the shell (subshell in this example) with `0`.

```
function sth() {
    local url="${1:?}"
...
}
(sth) ; echo $? # shows 0
```

Update: As Stéphane Chazelas says, this only happens in interactive usage.

Comment: I get `1`  with `zsh` 5.8. Which version are you using?

Comment: Note that it doesn't just exit the function, it exits the (sub)shell.

Comment: ZSH 4.3.6 also reports 1.

Comment: Correction, I get `1` in scripts (non-interactive shells), but `0` in interactive shells. That sounds related to https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2016/msg00755.html

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Any way to fix it in interactive usage?

Comment: You may want to report it as a possible bug to zsh-workers@zsh.org

Comment: Also, seems like if you break it down as `local var; var=${1?}` it works ok.

Comment: Having said that, it seems to me it would make more sense to *return* from the function with an error when the number of arguments is not as expected, rather than abort everything and return to the prompt (or exit the subshell if run from a subshell) as `${var?}` is meant to do (like `if (($# < 1)); then print -ru2 error:...; return 1; fi`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You're right. Is there a reason why your suggestion is not the default behavior for `:?`? Exiting everything is not a very good trade-off.

Comment: That syntax is from the Bourne shell (from the late 70s) which didn't have functions initially. It's mostly useful in scripts outside of functions.

Answer (score -1):

As explained in the comments, `${x:?}` itself cannot do that. However, what you want can be done easily with a conditional statement:

```bsh
% sth() { [[ -n $1 ]] || return; local url="$1" }
% sth; print $?
1
```

Comment: Can whoever downvoted this answer please explain _why?_